# REGEX expression: get the two letters after the slash or after the last dot

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to pick up the ISO code (two letters) of a country using a REGEX expression

For example, for the country `Ireland` the ISO code is `ie`. The ISO code could be found after the slash `/` or after the **last** `.`

This is my `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/country(?:/[^/]*([a-zA-Z-9]{2}))?/?$ gallery/gallery.php?country=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here are some valid url's... If available, I want to pick the ISO Code:

gallery/country

gallery/country/

gallery/country/`ie`

gallery/country/`ie`/

gallery/country/ireland

gallery/country/ireland/

gallery/country/ireland-love.`ie`

gallery/country/ireland-love.`ie`/

gallery/country/ireland.69-love.`ie`/

I've try to adapt the template formula that I use pretty much for all of my seo url's, but i'm having difficulties with this one. Here's what I've done so far.

```
^gallery/country(?:/[^/]*([a-zA-Z-9]{2}))?/?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/88azeh/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
^gallery/country/(?:.*[/.])?([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Jde3T/1). Details:

- `^` - start of input
- `gallery/country/` - a literal string
- `(?:.*[/.])?` - an optional pattern matching

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `[/.]` - a `/` or `.`
- `([a-zA-Z]{2})` - Group 1: two ASCII letters
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. Catching everything after `.` in a reference group and using it while rewriting here. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing any URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule \.([a-zA-Z]+){2}/?$ gallery/gallery.php?country=$1 [L]
```

---

---

Above will not check about URI's condition, to make it more specific to gallery only try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^gallery/country.*\.([a-zA-Z]+){2}/?$ gallery/gallery.php?country=$1 [L]
```